# Proof that quantum entanglement does not increase the asymptotic capacity of classical channel

Tags: entanglement, quantum-operation

Consider a classical channel $N_{X\rightarrow Y}$ which takes every input alphabet $x\in X$ to output alphabet $y\in Y$ with probability $P(y|x)_{Y|X}$. It is stated in many papers that even if the sender and receiver share entangled quantum states (or even no-signalling resources like a Popescu-Rohrlich box), they cannot increase the asymptotic capacity.

What is the proof of this statement?

**Notes**

A half-answer to this question is in [this work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9904023.pdf), where the authors comment

> By itself, prior entanglement between sender and receiver confers no
>   ability to transmit classical information, nor can it increase the
>   capacity of a classical channel above what it would have been without
>   the entanglement. This follows from the fact that local manipulation
>   of one of two entangled subsystems cannot influence the expectation of
>   any local observable of the other subsystem

However, this is a little mysterious to me since it is known ([see here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.5300.pdf)) that in other regimes (one shot, zero error, etc.), entanglement between the sender and receiver can be used to boost the capacity of a classical channel. However, all these advantages die away in the case where one uses the channel $n$ times and $n\rightarrow\infty$. Why is this so?